# EmptyParam was variable now a function - How to resolve legacy code?

Tags: delphi, com

I am just upgrading some old code written in Delphi 6 to Delphi XE2.  Unfortunately the code references a Word97 COM object for generating some .doc documents.  There is a direct uses clause of Word97 in the code.

I have to keep the document generated in the same Word format as it is used by an old Crystal Report and another 3rd party app which requries that format of the document.

So, to the question.  Because I am using the Word97 in the uses clause, the compiler complains about Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical whenever an EmptyParam variable is used.  This is coming straight out of the Word97.pas source file.  This is because EmptyParam is now declared as a function and not a variable.

what is the best way to deal with this?  Should I copy the Delphi 6 source files (Word97.pas et al) say into my local directory, directly add them to my project, together with System.Variants.pas and change the Compiler Directive of my app to include EMPTYPARAM_VAR?  I haven't tried that, but hopefully it would declare EmptyParam as a variable then. Or perhaps there's an easier solution.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here's a little more background info, even though I have accepted an answer, for future reference.  Here's an example of the code (AddClaimsLetter is the "Application" COM object - ie TWordApplication):

```
AddClaimsLetter.Documents.Open(Wordfile, EmptyParam, EmptyParam,
                        EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam,
                        EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
```

Without changing anything, the EmptyParam arguments here failed at compile time stating "E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical".

However, because I wanted to keep Word97 (which is in OCX/Server in Delphi 6 Ent. installation folder), I did need to copy the .pas files into my local project file and declare a variable that was used in place of EmptyParam (because these files attempted to compile too and I got the same compiler error as above).

So all working now, but I might discuss with management upgrading to a later version of Office for this App!

Thanks

Comment: I don't have a Word97.pas file in my Delphi XE2, nor in my Delphi 2010. Is that because I didn't install it (perfectly possible) or is it because it's no longer available? Can you ctrl+enter on the file name to make sure the file actually comes from your Delphi XE2 installation and you didn't accidentally bring it from your D6 install?

Comment: I don't have Word97.pas on Delphi7 either!

Comment: I don't recall any problems with EmptyParam when I upgraded Delphi. Rather than describing your code, could you show it. Rather than describing the error message could you quote it exactly. Copying D6 source files, especially Variants.pas is not going to be the solution.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Try passing `EmptyParam` to any of the parameters in `function Open(var FileName: OleVariant; var ConfirmConversions: OleVariant; var ReadOnly: OleVariant; var AddToRecentFiles: OleVariant; var PasswordDocument: OleVariant; var PasswordTemplate: OleVariant; var Revert: OleVariant; var WritePasswordDocument: OleVariant; var WritePasswordTemplate: OleVariant; var Format: OleVariant; var Encoding: OleVariant; var Visible: OleVariant; var OpenAndRepair: OleVariant; var DocumentDirection: OleVariant; var NoEncodingDialog: OleVariant): WordDocument; safecall;`

Comment: @hvd: where did you get that declaration and why are all parameters var parameters? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, as scary as it looks, that's how Delphi imports the Type Library for Word.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I copied it from Delphi XE's WordXP.pas. And that's exactly the problem: they *shouldn't* be `var`, but they are. And now that `EmptyParam` is a function, it's no longer a valid function argument for a `var` parameter.

Comment: @Cosmin and hvd: Holy macaroni! Then I would follow the advise to store the result of the function in a variable.

Comment: @CosminPrund: Delphi 7 comes with Word97.pas, it is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi7\Ocx\Servers

Comment: @The_Fox it might be that certain editions of Delphi 7 don't have this file. If I remember correctly the feature matrix indicated something like that. Can't find it online any more though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I quick workaround for the problem might be to declare a local variable of type OleVariant and assign it the result of the function EmptyParam.

Comment: I would call it THE solution, not a workaround. If Delphi XE2 made EmptyParam a function, than this is the way to go. Copying old Word*.pas files is not going to help.

Comment: +1 for this concise version; I put in a more verbose answer that explains the why (basically: when passing multiple `var` parameters, make sure they all point to different variables).

Comment: Thanks. This is what I ended up implementation.  Thanks to all others for their input

Answer (score 7):

For every `var` parameter, you should add a local variable that you fill with the `EmptyParam` call.

The reason is that all `var` parameters are passed by reference. If you pass the same variable at multiple references, you can encounter the following issue (simplified using Integers).

```
Before: VarParameter=-1
Before: A=-1
Before: B=-1
After: A=2
After: B=2
After: VarParameter=2
EAssertionFailed: Assertion failure
```

This is the code that shows the risk:

```
program TheVarParameterRisk;

procedure AssignParameters(var A: Integer; var B: Integer);
begin
  Writeln('Before: A=', A);
  Writeln('Before: B=', B);
  A := 1;
  B := 2;
  Writeln('After: A=', A);
  Writeln('After: B=', B);
  Assert(A = 1);
end;

var
  VarParameter: Integer;

begin
  try
    VarParameter := -1;
    try
      Writeln('Before: VarParameter=', VarParameter);
      AssignParameters(VarParameter, VarParameter);
    finally
      Writeln('After: VarParameter=', VarParameter);
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

You see that in the `AssignParameters` the `Assert` fails, because the caller passed the same reference into the two `var` parameters.

This is exactly the reason that `EmptyParam` became a function: it should never be passed as a `var` parameter.

People were complaining about bugs in Delphi (for instance [here](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=61255)) that caused overwrites of the `EmptyParam` value.

That problem is solved now that `EmptyParam` is a function. When you need to pass it as a `var` parameter, use a local intermediate.

Notes:

- If you (because your imported API indicates you should) have to pass `EmptyParam` to a `var` parameter, then essentially you have problem in itself: a `var` parameter means that something is going to be changed, which means that passing `EmptyParam` (or a local variable having the same content) is preventing the change.
- If you think the Type Library Importer generates the wrong code (that has `var` parameters in stead of `const` parameters), then either the imported type library has the wrong parameter flags, or (if the parameter flags are OK) it is buggy (and you should file a bug report at https://quality.embarcadero.com (this used to be the search engine indexed http://qc.embarcadero.com but that has been shut down; https://quality.embarcadero.com requires a free account to search).

**Edit:**

The fact that you have to pass `EmptyParam` in to a `var` parameter is a very strong hint into my point that that the function that is called might acually use those parameters and will fail. Just like my example function fails.  (Yes, the function documentation might lure you into using multiple `EmptyParam` parameters that in fact are not meant to be that empty at all; I've often seen documentation say A and actual functions perform B).

Comment: While most of this is at least technically accurate, the reason it's called `EmptyParam` is because you're not intending it to  be used. Therefore, you can allocate a single variant, populate it with either `EmptyParam` or `EmptyParam()` (actually, the first will work in both cases, as the parens on function call with no params are optional), and reuse the same variant in all places you're using `EmptyParam`. `EmptyParam` by definition means "a placeholder for a parameter I have no intention of using ever".

Comment: +1 for explaining possible pitfalls with using variable placeholders and the **reason** why emptyparam is now a function.

Comment: @Jeroen, the fact that the function might change them internally is only relevant if *you* intend to access something in them afterwards. If (as in this (most?) cases with Office automation) you're not, it doesn't matter. :)

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).

Answer (score 1):

> Should I copy the Delphi 6 source files (Word97.pas et al) say into my local directory, directly add them to my project, together with System.Variants.pas and change the Compiler Directive of my app to include EMPTYPARAM_VAR? I haven't tried that, but hopefully it would declare EmptyParam as a variable then.

You are probably legally allowed to copy the Word97.pas from your much older Delphi to the new one, but then you'll need to "upgrade" it to work with the new compiler. You're likely going to face a lot more problems, mostly because Delphi XE2 is Unicode enabled and Delphi 6 is not. If that unit is what I think it is (as mentioned I don't have it on the 3 versions of Delphi I've got handy and checked) then it's a wrapper for OLE Automating Word - ie, it's full of hard to understand system code and lots of method declarations with no implementation. This last bit, method declarations with no implementation, makes it *very* hard to change: if you change something and it compiles it doesn't mean it's right - you'll only find at runtime if it works or not.

What you should probably do:

- <strike>Re-import the type library for Word 97 (I assume that's what the Word97.pas is) and re-write your export code to generate the word document using this new library.</strike> **Edit:** *Apparently re-importing the TypeLibrary produces unusable code.*
- Write a DLL in Delphi6 that uses the old Word97.pas and use that from Delphi XE2. Not very elegant but will work.
- Re-think your strategy around whatever the current offer for Word automation is.

Comment: Importing the Word type library will lead to function declarations with the same problem as what's already in Word97.pas: for some reason the parameters that should be `const` are detected as `var`.

Comment: @vhd, I can't say much about importing the Word 97 type library as I don't need it and haven't used it. All I can tell you is that I just imported the Type Library for Word 2007 (that's the version I've got) and it compiles just fine. And while not impossible, I doubt the import would NOT work, as that would be a serious Delphi bug.

Comment: Yes, that works the same as with Word 97: the fact that `const` parameters are marked `var` means the unit itself will compile fine, but certain uses of the functions, as in the question, that *should* be accepted aren't. At any rate, re-importing the type library will not be useful in solving the problem.

Comment: Note that `const` has a totally different meaning in Delphi and should not be used when passing data to modules written in other languages. Types like OLEVariants are probably always passed by reference.

Comment: @Rudy I'm not sure I follow that comment.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Depending on the type, `const` may cause a pass by reference, and for `OleVariant` does so. See `ActiveX.IPropertyBag.Write` for the first example I could find where this is used in the RTL.

Comment: @hvd: an Olevariant is always passed by reference, indeed. Const, in Delphi, is a sign that it doesn't have to be copied over by the function. It does not have that meaning in other languages, and these do not follow the Delphi const mechanism, so it is safest to declare all OleVariant parameters var (pass by reference).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis An unadorned `OleVariant` parameter is copied by the caller, not the callee, if the calling convention is `stdcall`. You're thinking of the default calling convention. Regardless, it doesn't change that `const OleVariant` in Delphi is a suitable parameter type in Delphi for what the type library marks as "[in, optional] VARIANT*". To Delphi, it means a reference to an existing object can be passed because the object won't be modified. That is compatible with what actually happens, is it not?